# Marketing Cloud Connect - Tracking with a new connection

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, history-tracking

If we disconnected our org from once Marketing Cloud account and connected it to a new MID thats not connected to the old one, if we send in the new account to the same contact keys, will tracking data be merged at the contact level in the SF org? We suspect there will be a conflict with jobIDs when the new instance runs job IDs into SF tracking where those already exist from the old account. Has anyone run into this situation before and have any insight to a possible solution? If possible we are looking to just have a smooth cutover and retain tracking from the old connection. This wouldn't be a multi-org setup, just moving the connection from one MID to another.

Answer (score 0):

We got a direct answer form SF about this question and wanted to post the results.

Since the connector factors in the MID of the MC account as a key, the tracking data can co-exist on the same contact record between the old MID and the new MID connections.